# SUM a date range within another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to SUM a date range on another sheet ("TRADES") (the date range is ALL of January and the date column is column B:B, but this also includes all the other months of the year)

And the column i would like to SUM is column N.

Any help is appreciated!

I am currently trying this, but it is not working:

```
=SUMIF(TRADES!N:N,TRADES!B:B, ">="&DATE(2021,1,1), TRADES!B:B, "<="&DATE(2021,1,31))
```

Comment: "CURRENTLY TRYING THIS BUT NO WORKING" is not a problem description. What happens when you try it? Why is that wrong? If you get an error, quote it in full. If you get a wrong result, explain what, why it is wrong, and what the correct result would be. Show example input data, desired output data, and current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This base formula should work. You will need to update the following:

- Sum Range on TRADES worksheet
- Date Range on TRADES worksheet
- Cell/Formula reference for the first of the desired month you wish to sum (January = 1/1/21)

=SUMIFS(TRADES![SUM RANGE],TRADES![DATE RANGE],">="&[Cell Ref to Start of Desired Sum Month],TRADES![DATE RANGE],"<="&EOMONTH(Cell Ref to Start of Desired Sum Month,0))

If you need further explanation, see this resource: [How to sum by month - SpreadsheetWeb](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/sum-month/)